# Capture dropped word warning from react-wordcloud

Tags: reactjs, console, word-cloud

I understand that react-wordcloud will occasionally drop some words from the cloud if they are too long and high frequency and hence dont fit in the assigned cloud dimensions. If this happens it is logged to the console as a warning. I am wondering if there is anyway that this console message could be captured so that you could send an alert or other message to the user in the window rather than the console.